# computed properties returns undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is code to display students table, i try to use commputed property for students full name but it displays UNDEFINED in the fullname column

```
<tr v-for="student in students" :key="student.id">
          <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
         <td><a href="#" class="nav-link">{{ student.index_no | uppercase }} 
         </a></td>
         <td>{{fullname | capitalize}}</td>
         <td>{{fullname | capitalize}}</td>
                <td>{{student.department | capitalize}}</td>
                <td>{{ student.course | capitalize}}</td>
                <td>{{ student.regular_or_weekend | capitalize }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.nationality | capitalize}}</td>
                <td>{{ student.created_at |datetime }}</td>
```

this is the vuejs code, all the methods works fine with the exception of computed property which displays UNDEFINED. i have excluded the methods

```
 <script>

import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'

export default {

    data () {
        return {
            editmode : true, // for edit conditional
            students: {}, //student object

            // Create a new form instance
            form: new Form({
                    id: '',
                    index_no:'',
                    firstname: '',
                    middlename: '',
                    lastname: '',
                    department: '',
                    course:'',
                    regular_or_weekend:'',
                    nationality:''
                   })
                } //end of data()
            },
      methods:{

           }     
     computed:{
        fullname:function(){
           return this.firstname+" "+this.middlename+" "+this.lastname;
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have an array of students which means you cannot use a computed property in this way as this implies there is only a single `fullname` property when in fact there are multiple (one for each student)

You have a couple possible options here. (code untested)

### Option 1

Make a new component called Student, and pass the student object from your v-for into it as a prop like so

`<tr v-for="student in students" :key="student.id">
     <Student :student="student"/>
 </tr>`

the Student component would contain all the HTML to render a single student from the list and you could make your computed property similar to how you did originally now that the Student component is only rendering a single Student. This is probably the "best practice" way to do it.

`computed:{
        fullname:function(){
           return this.student.firstname+" "+this.student.middlename+" "+this.student.lastname;
        }
    }`

### Option 2

You can use a computed property to simply add a new property to your students array

`computed:{
        studentsWithFullname: function(){
           return this.students.forEach(element => {
               element.fullname = element.firstname + " " + element.middlename + " " + element.lastname
           });
        }
    }`

then iterate over the "studentsWithFullname" array instead of the students array (or whatever you want to call it) and output fullname

### Option 3

Don't bother with any of this and just use `student.firstname + " " + student.middlename + " " + student.lastname` directly in your template as you have done already

Comment: i made the changes but fullname is now showing an empty string

Comment: This would make sense as it seems your names are initialized to empty strings when you create the form instance. Try setting firstname middlename and lastname to a value other than empty string and see if it works.

Comment: <td>{{student.firstname+" "+student.middlename+" "+student.lastname}}</td>. when i used this works, but i create a function or computed property, that is where i get a undefined

Comment: it worked when i set the first,middle and last name. how do i fix this

Comment: Oh I see, you have an array of students. I'll revise my answer when I get home in a few

Answer (score 0):

Use a **method** instead of a computed property, passing in the student.

Template:

```
<tr v-for="student in students" :key="student.id">
   <td>{{getFullName(student) | capitalize}}</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
methods: {
  getFullName (student) {
    return student.firstname + ' ' + student.middlename + ' ' + student.lastname;
  }
}
```